# Unexpected Legend and Values in Plotly Graphs with Buttons

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I have been attempting to create a plotly object that uses buttons to switch between two graphs. However, the legend and values that appear when I click a button are not what I expect. I have been using the following guides for reference:

[Dropdowns](https://plotly.com/r/dropdowns/) 
[Custom buttons](https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/)

Here is an example of the data I am using:

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Create MWE dataframe 
set.seed(32)
ae_data <- data.frame(
  Program = rep(c("Biology", "Math", "History", "English", "Computer Science",
                  "Chemistry", "Business", "Philosophy", "Psychology", "Physics"), 5),
  Year = rep(2018:2022, each = 10),
  Application = round(runif(50, min = 100, max = 900), digits = 0),
  Enrolment = round(runif(50, min = 150, max = 950), digits = 0)
)
```

Here is the code I used to generate the graph:

```
# Generate the appropriate number of colors
graph_colors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(length(unique(ae_data$Program)))

# Create graph
ae_data %>%
  plot_ly(
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines + markers",
    colors = graph_colors
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    x = ~Year,
    y = ~Application,
    color = ~Program
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    x = ~Year,
    y = ~Enrolment, 
    color = ~Program,
    visible = F
  ) %>%
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        type = "buttons",
        buttons = list(
          list(
            label = "Application",
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(visible = c(F, T)),
                        list(yaxis = list(title = "Application")))
          ),
          list(
            label = "Enrolment",
            method = "update",
            args = list(list(visible = c(T, F)),
                        list(yaxis = list(title = "Enrolment")))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

What ends up happening is that the legend and values for my Application and Enrolment frames get mixed up as soon as I click on one of my buttons. I get half of my application AND enrolment frames on click for each of my buttons. I expect the buttons to switch between the frames I've identified in my traces above based on my arguments for updatemenus. I've tried using the other "method" inputs, but "update" seems to be the correct one based on the documentation.

Here are some images to illustrate my expected and actual values:

Expected graph for Application:

[image]

Actual graph for Application on click:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this issue is to update the layout of the graph using the update_layout() function in Plotly. Specifically, you can use the legend argument to specify the behavior of the legend when the data is updated. Try the following code:

```
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~year, y = ~value, color = ~group, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", hoverinfo = "text",
               text = ~paste("Group: ", group, "<br>Year: ", year, "<br>Value: ", value))

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      type = "buttons",
      showactive = TRUE,
      buttons = list(
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list(list(y = list(~data$value[data$group == "A"], ~data$value[data$group == "B"])),
                         list(type = "scatter", mode = "lines")),
             label = "All"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list(list(y = list(~data$value[data$group == "A"])),
                         list(type = "scatter", mode = "lines")),
             label = "Group A"),
        list(method = "restyle",
             args = list(list(y = list(~data$value[data$group == "B"])),
                         list(type = "scatter", mode = "lines")),
             label = "Group B")
      )
    )
  ),
  legend = list(
    traceorder = "normal",
    font = list(
      family = "sans-serif",
      size = 12,
      color = "black"
    ),
    bgcolor = "#E2E2E2",
    bordercolor = "#FFFFFF",
    borderwidth = 2
  )
)

fig
```